# In Excel VBA get the Path that is used when using "Save As" (document created from template!)

Tags: excel, vba, templates, sharepoint

How can we get the suggested path that Excel gives when using "Save as" of a document that is created from a template on SharePoint?
The document isn't saved so it doesn't have a path yet. Although when we use "Save As" the correct document library is suggested in the Save window. We need that suggestion in VBA (to create a subfolder in that suggestion and save the document automatically by using a macro that runs on open).

Anyone who can help us finding the path property that is stored (and used while saving) on a document which is created using an Excel template through SharePoint?

Extra info: We tried all things like Application.TemplatesPath, CurDir etc. It should be a property that SharePoint stores specifically in the document itself; it isn't a last known location or something like that. We think so because we did several tests. When opening a file and close the internet connections; Excel tries to get connected to SharePoint and when it takes too long it shows the default location. Also created a new document from template, saved another workbook in different local folder, afterwards save the template document and the suggestion is still correct.
We created a .xltm Excel template which now is the document template of a SharePoint content type. When we press the button "New document" button in de SharePoint ribbon, a new document is created.

Answer (score 1):

This started getting me to the right direction...  Hopefully it helps

```
DefaultFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
If DefaultFilePath = "" Then DefaultFilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).InitialFileName = DefaultFilePath
MsgBox (Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).InitialFileName)
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(
Thanks for thinking with me though.
- Application.DefaultFilePath
- Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).InitialFileName
- msoFileDialogSaveAs
all give the standard C:\users (default of Excel). When I press F12 first thing in status bar below is Contacting: \\sharepoint.lan\DavWWWRoot\re...

This one is hard...

Comment: It should be somewhere in the document settings. If we get an overview of all properties, I probably can just use search to find the name of the property... Someone knows how to show all document property fields?